# Jenkins ignores trend graph configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

I've set up Jenkins as a service on my Windows 7 developer PC in order to provide rational arguments to why we should use Jenkins and not Bamboo in the company.

I've installed the 'Analysis Collector Plugin': https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Analysis+Collector+Plugin, but Jenkins ignores my configuration of the trend graph:
[image]

After I save the config, it still displays the default graph with the default settings:
[image]

I know the graph settings are stored as cookies, which is why I use the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080` instead of `http://localhost:8080`, but still I can't get it to display the right graph.

Jenkins v1.538

Static Analysis Collector Plug-in v1.38

Comment: Run a new build after the configuration gets change (just to be sure).

Comment: Yes, this was also my first idea, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has since been resolved in later versions of the [Static Analysis Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Analysis+Collector+Plugin). Please download and install the latest version [1.51](https://github.com/jenkinsci/analysis-collector-plugin/compare/analysis-collector-1.50...analysis-collector-1.51) and upon restart the issue should be resolved.

There is an interdependency of this plugin with the [Static Code Analysis Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Static+Code+Analysis+Plug-ins), so you will need to update that plugin to the latest version as well.

Lastly, and most importantly, you will need to (and should anyway) update Jenkins from version 1.538 to a more recent version to remain compatible with the newest version of the Analysis Collector Plugin. For this reason (as well as many others), I highly reccomend the latest version of Jenkins as well, which at the time of writing this is [2.63](https://jenkins.io/changelog/).